# How to use css counters in nested lists without parent index while not using a separate counter for each level

Tags: javascript, html, css

My code example:

```css
.list {
    counter-reset: section;                
}

.item::before {
    counter-increment: section;             
    content: counters(section, ".") '. ';   
}

.list .list .item {
    margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class='list'>
      <div class='item'>item</div>        
      <div class='item'>item              
        <div class='list'>
          <div class='item'>item</div>     
          <div class='item'>item</div>     
          <div class='item'>item </div>
 
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='item'>item</div>         
      <div class='item'>item</div>         
    </div>
```

The above code outputs：

```
1. item
2. item
   2.1. item
   2.2. item
   2.3. item
3. item
4. item
```

I want the child items not to have a parent index, like the following:

```
1. item
2. item
   1. item
   2. item
   3. item
3. item
4. item
```

I am aware that this can be achieved with a separate counter for each level, but then you need to write out the CSS for each counter. In my real use case, there are unpredictable levels and I don't control the HTML. There could be 50 levels and I can't possibly write out all the 50 sets of CSS rules. That's why I use the counters() function, which handles multiple levels automatically. The question is, the counters() function comes with the parent index. Is it possible at all to get rid of it?

If pure CSS can't do it, can we do it with the help of JS?

Comment: Not without javascript, no.

Comment: @Paulie_D I'm also OK with JS. If you write an answer with JS and solve this problem, I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks funny, but you might use `counter()` not `counters()`:

```css
.list {
  counter-reset: section;
}

.item::before {
  counter-increment: section;
  content: counter(section) '. ';
}

.list .list .item {
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class='list'>
  <div class='item'>item</div>
  <div class='item'>item
    <div class='list'>
      <div class='item'>item</div>
      <div class='item'>item
        <div class='list'>
          <div class='item'>item</div>
          <div class='item'>item</div>
          <div class='item'>item </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class='item'>item </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='item'>item</div>
  <div class='item'>item</div>
</div>
```

BTW, it's weird to make lists with `<div>`s when `<ul>` and `<ol>` are available and intended exactly for that purpose.

Comment: Thank you. I played with counter() and thought each level must have a unique counter name. I didn't know it also handles multi-levels. BTW, as I said in the question, I don't control the HTML.

Comment: @Betty, counters work similar to `var()` they have a scope. In your case, since counter is being reset at `.list`, in fact you have a separate counter (with the same name) in scope of every `.list`. The latter may be confusing =))

Comment: It is a bit confusing. The docs and tutorials I've found aren't making it clear, either. Luckily I got you. :) Thank you very much.

Comment: @Betty, happy to help!